# Execution error with .so file

Tags: command-line, shared-library

When running a server and trying to connect to a web socket I have an execution error:

```
./cameraserver: symbol lookup error: 
/home/ivan/Desktop/jderobot/JdeRobot/src/stable/interfaces/cpp/jderobot/libJderobotInterfaces.so: 
undefined symbol: _ZN11IceInternal11BasicStream5writeEx
```

If I do `ldd` I see:

```
libcolorspacesmm.so => /home/ivan/Desktop/jderobot/JdeRobot/src/stable/libs/visionlib/colorspaces/libcolorspacesmm.so (0x00007f1c289da000)
libJderobotInterfaces.so => /home/ivan/Desktop/jderobot/JdeRobot/src/stable/interfaces/cpp/jderobot/libJderobotInterfaces.so (0x00007f1c284de000)
```

And these two files are not there. Both are in: `/usr/local/lib/jderobot/` How can I change the path to the .so files?

I am working with Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Create soft links i.e. `ln -s /usr/local/lib/jderobot/libcolorspacesmm.so /home/ivan/Desktop/jderobot/JdeRobot/src/stable/libs/visionlib/colorspaces/libcolorspacesmm.so` and the second one too `ln -s /usr/local/lib/jderobot/libJderobotInterfaces.so /home/ivan/Desktop/jderobot/JdeRobot/src/stable/interfaces/cpp/jderobot/libJderobotInterfaces.so`

Comment: @heemayl make it as answer

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give a concrete solution without knowing the background of the issue.

As a workaround you can create symbolic links :

```
ln -s /where/it/is /where/it/needs/to/be
```

So, for your case:

```
ln -s /usr/local/lib/jderobot/libcolorspacesmm.so /home/ivan/Desktop/jderobot/JdeRobot/src/stable/libs/visionlib/colorspaces/libco‌​lorspacesmm.so

ln -s /usr/local/lib/jderobot/libJderobotInterfaces.so /home/ivan/Desktop/jderobot/JdeRobot/src/stable/interfaces/cpp/jderobot/libJdero‌​botInterfaces.so
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @heemayl, but It doesn't work. I think I have to recompile the app. When I recompile I will get back to post the results!!